# Weird update behavior: Template constantly calls display function

Tags: angular, typescript

I noticed a weird behavior. If I have an `input` which has `focus` and `focusout` callbacks, a nested component which has just a simple `displaySomething`-like method gets called way too many times.

Just take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weird-updates?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-data.component.ts) example (note the log messages in the console).

In particular it's about `displayDataContent()` in

```xml
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let content of data.contents">
      {{ displayDataContent(content) }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why is this function getting called so many times? I wouldn't have noticed this behavior if I didn't place a `console.log` statement in there earlier.

How can this be avoided? I don't see why this is happening in the first place..

Comment: This is because of Angulars change detection. You might have to disable angular change detection and implement when you want to watch for changes.

Comment: Angular isn't magic. It detects changes to know when to update the DOM. To detect changes, it needs to call your method to check its returned value has changed since the last time it checked.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Okay, that makes sense. I did not know that change detection will also work on - how do you call that - "bound functions" (?). As stated by joh04667 that's definitely not what I'd want so I better try to avoid this.

Comment: @JBNizet Never claimed there's any magic involved. I did not know that Angular actually binds a function and checks whether its output changed. Thought this only works on properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. This is data bound to the template, and Angular's change detection cycles check bound properties to see if their value has changed and need to be updated in the component or its view. Since this is a method, the only way Angular can check to see if its value has changed is by calling it and comparing the new result to the current value.

In many articles, you'll often see this behavior cited as bad practice because multiple semi-expensive method calls can significantly harm the speed of the page. However, a very simple method that returns a value with little or no calculation is hardly any different than using getters or native value accessors, so this practice isn't *always* bad...but, it's still (slightly) more work on the stack and will hold up change detection until the method completes.

For this reason, it's often considered best practice to either unwrap the value to a component property before binding or to use a pipe. If the value is going to be changing due to events outside of the component, an `Observable` with an `async` pipe is the most preferred pattern; the `Observable`s emissions mean reactive change detection as opposed to polling.

You can also strategically tell Angular to turn off or restrict the change detection for the entire component and then use the `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually run a change detection cycle if needed...while that's a speedup overall, change detection is one of the most appealing things about Angular as a framework, and it's usually a better design choice to invert that control to Angular when you can.

Comment: I see. very nice answer. I kind of thought it might have to do with change detection and as you mentioned - I had big concerns about performance there. However, I did not know that having functions return values for templates is considered bad practice. Then again, with what you said in mind, it makes sense. Thanks for that elaborate answer!

Comment: glad I could help!